# Is there some way to make $_SESSION data "per directory" in PHP?

Tags: php, session-state

So I had a website with login page, located in a subdirectory named "login".

I recently changed webhosts, and now my login page does not log me in. The session data is not showing on the main page [I have it set to print_r($_SESSION); and the only data it shows is sessionstart].

But when I click the login page again, it shows I am logged in!

And when I move the login page to the MAIN directory, it logs me in, which leads me to believe the $_SESSION data is per directory somehow...

The PHP version is the same as the old webhost (7.2), and it is the same type of server (Apache on Linux). Not sure how session data could work on one webhost and NOT on another.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, so it looks like it is being caused by the php.ini file in the main directory. But the only entries in it are **upload_max_filesize = 64M**  and  **post_max_size = 64M** .  I tried copying it to the login folder, but it still won't keep session data between the 2 pages. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Session_start() should be present on all scripts where you need a session, can you show us the code where the problem is located ?

Comment: i have ob_start(); and session_start(); at the top of the login and main page. There is a lot of other code involved, but even when I simplified it and just had those two and the print_r($_SESSION); on the pages, with a header redirect on the login page, it didn't show the session data on the main page. Also, both pages have the same session_id when I tested them.